# High-dimensional shapes with known volume formulas

Tags: geometry, volume, big-list, polytopes

There don't seem to be a lot of high-dimensional shapes whose volume, surface area, etc. can be expressed in a concise way.  The examples I know of are:

1. Spheres
2. Cubes (or parallelotopes, more generally)
3. Simplices
4. Zonotopes

What other classes of high dimensional objects admit relatively simple volume (or area, etc.) formulas?

---

EDIT: Since zonotopes are the most unfamiliar of my examples, here's a reference: Chapter 9 of "[Computing the Continuous Discretely](https://matthbeck.github.io/ccd.html)".  To summarize, a zonotope is a set of the form
$$\{a_1 \vec{x}_1 + \cdots + a_m \vec{x}_m \:|\: a_1,\dots,a_m\in[0,1]\}$$
where $\vec{x}_1,\dots,\vec{x}_m\in \mathbb{R}^n$ are fixed.  This is like a parallelotope, except the vectors $\vec{x}_j$ need not be linearly independent (e.g. $m$ can be greater than $n$).  The volume of such a zonotope is given by
$$ \sum_{S\subset \{1,\dots,m\}, |S|=n} |\det[x_i]_{i\in S}|$$
which means: "Take any n of the m vectors $\vec{x_i}$ and compute the volume of the parallelotope formed by these n vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Sum over all such parallelotopes and you get the volume of the zonotope."

Comment: Can you share a formula for the volume of zonotopes?

Answer (score 4):

(1) A minor addition to your list:
Ellipsoids are just linear transformations of spheres.
If $M$ is a linear transformation applied to sphere $S$, then
the volume of the ellipsoid is vol$(S) \cdot$ det$(M)$.

Here is an explicit reference: Wilson, A. John. "Volume of n-dimensional ellipsoid." *Sciencia Acta Xaveriana*. 2009.

---

[image: EllVol]

<sup>That must be $a_1 a_2 a_3 \cdots$. Typo: commas → multiplication.</sup>

---

(2) I found this reference but not the paper itself:

> "The $(n+1)$-Volume of an $n$-Torus." [Link](http://citation.allacademic.com/meta/p_mla_apa_research_citation/4/3/9/0/5/p439051_index.html).

Answer (score 3):

A couple more examples I've found:

1) Cross-polytopes.  These are generalizations of an octohedron.  Wikipedia has a [nice article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-polytope) on them, and the standard n-dimensional cross-polytope has volume $\frac{2^n}{n!}$.

2) Cones.  A cone is formed from a base shape of codimension 1 and a point at some height $h$ above the base.  In n dimensions, if the base has $(n-1)$ volume $A$, then the cone has $n$ volume $\frac{Ah}{n}$.